# Directus on remote server

Tags: node.js, pm2, directus

I have an app on remote server. I use directus  of this app and I have a site example.com. I want to make able the route example.com/admin manage content . I try to start directus with command `pm2 start npm --start`, but I get this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D77HO.png)

Can you help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off serving Directus on a subdomain (admin.example.com), this will separate the back-end from the front-end. The root URL for the Directus install is the API URL, followed by /admin for the editing interface.

If you have installed Directus under /admin then the API will likely be available at example.com/admin and I believe the interface will be under example.com/admin/admin, which is why I suggest a subdomain.

I generally use mgmt.example, cms.example or similar variations.